# How to base awk selection on contents of 1 field?

Tags: awk

How can I select all the records that have '2' as the second field?

My data is:

```
$ cat numbers.txt 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24
```

My awk is:

```
 awk '$2 - /^2$/ {print}' numbers.txt
```

but I get all lines, not just the first one:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [matching operator ~](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04), not [subtraction operator -](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02):

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /^2$/' file
```

or use equality operator `==` like [@glenn jackman's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170725/38906).

But let take a look at your previous solution, to explain that why you got all the lines.

```
awk '$2 - /^2$/ {print}' numbers.txt
```

Here, with each line input, if expression `$2 - /^2$/` is true, you will print this line, else do nothing. Because you got all the lines, so it seems that expression `$2 - /^2$/` was always evaluated to true.

How `awk` evaluated that expression?

When you use subtraction operator, the type result is numeric. `$2` variable was a number, but `/^2$/` is a regular expression, what is its numeric value?

Well, from [POSIX awk documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04):

> When an ERE token appears as an expression in any context other than
>   as the right-hand of the '˜' or "!˜" operator or as one of the
>   built-in function arguments described below, the value of the
>   resulting expression shall be the equivalent of:
>
> $0 ˜ /ere/

So, your `awk` program become:

```
awk '$2 - ($0 ~ /^2$/) {print}' numbers.txt
```

You can see, each input line will be checked with regular expression `/^2$/`. Because none of your input lines matched, the result of expression `$0 ~ /^2$/` will be 0.

With your input, all second fields have value greater than 0 (subtract to 0 make it unchanged), which are true value in `awk`. So expression `$2 - /^2$/` is always true, cause `awk` print all lines.

Answer (score 3):

`~` is the pattern match operator, not `-`. But if you're testing for equality, use the equality operator `==`

```
awk '$2 == 2' numbers.txt
```

Comment: Note that `$2 == 2` would match on `002`, `2.0`, `2e0`, `20e-1`, or `+2`; `+$2 == 2` would match on those and `2whatever` (including `2,200` regardless of whether the decimal separator in the user's locale is `,` or `.`); `$2 == "2"` would match on `2` only. `gawk -n '$2 == 2' would match on `0x2` and `0x2whatever` as well. `gawk --use-lc-numeric '$2 == 2'` would honour the locale when it comes to the decimal separator (would match on `2,0` but not on `2.0` in a French locale for instance).